# Program will not return a value back

Tags: arrays, user-interface, netbeans, methods, parallel-processing

So, I am creating a GUI in which you are able to calculate either the molar mass, mass or moles and I cannot seem to get a calculation back when I call my methods. I am using parallel arrays and I am thinking that may be the problem. Btw, molarMass was declared globally but I didn't know how to format it on here. Thanks.

```
private void btnGoActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      

int indexOfElements = cmbElements.getSelectedIndex();
Double numberOfMass = Double.parseDouble(txtInputMass.getText());
Double numberOfMoles = Double.parseDouble(txtInputMoles.getText());


    if (chkMoles.isSelected()==true)
   {
   txtAnswer.setText(solveForMoles(numberOfMass).toString() + " mol");  
   }
   else if (chkMolarMass.isSelected()==true)
   {
   txtAnswer.setText(solveForMolarMass(numberOfMass, numberOfMoles).toString() + "             
   g/mol");

   }
   else if (chkMass.isSelected()==true)
   {
   txtAnswer.setText(solveForMass(numberOfMoles).toString() + " g");
   }
   else
   {
   txtAnswer.setText ("Please make a selection");
   }


private Double solveForMoles (double mass){

int indexOfElements = cmbElements.getSelectedIndex();
double numberOfMoles = mass/molarMass[indexOfElements];
return (Double.parseDouble (x.format(numberOfMoles)));
}
private Double solveForMass (double moles){
int indexOfElements = cmbElements.getSelectedIndex();
double numberOfMass = moles*molarMass[indexOfElements];
return (Double.parseDouble (x.format(numberOfMass)));
}

 private Double solveForMolarMass (double masss, double moless){

    double numberOfMolarMass = masss/moless;
    return (Double.parseDouble(x.format (numberOfMolarMass)));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend that you make some changes:

1. Encapsulate all those calculations into a sensible Java object rather than parallel arrays.  Java's an object-oriented language.
2. Move all the calculations outside of the UI.  Write that calculation object, JUnit test it thoroughly, then introduce it into the UI.  Computer science, and all problem solving, is best done using divide and conquer.